# Run Flask app in Kivy app when a button is pressed

Tags: python, flask, kivy

Is there a way that I could run Kivy and Flask at the same time in a Kivy app? Furthermore, I need the app so once you click a button in the Kivy app, that triggers a function where a Flask web page is started. Then, using the Python builtin webbrowser module, I need it to automatically open the web page in the default browser.

When this code is ran, I get no error. Just the Kivy app freezes and does not respond anymore.

My code so far:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from flask import Flask
from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
import webbrowser

Builder.load_file('design.kv')

answers = []

class CalcScreen(Screen):
    def list_view(self):
        self.manager.current = "list_screen"
    def cround_view(self):
        self.manager.current = "round_calc_screen"
    def calculate(self):
        LengthVal = float(self.ids.length.text)
        WidthVal = float(self.ids.width.text)
        ThicknessVal = float(self.ids.thickness.text)

        FinalCalc = LengthVal * WidthVal * ThicknessVal / 144
        FinalCalc = round(FinalCalc,1)
        answers.append(FinalCalc)

        self.ids.board_feet.text = str(FinalCalc)

class ListScreen(Screen):
    def calc_view(self):
        self.manager.current = "calc_screen"
    def UpdateInfo(self):
        tot = 0
        for num in answers:
            tot += num

        self.ids.total_board_feet.text = str(round(tot,1))
        self.ids.total_boards.text = str(len(answers))
        self.ids.list.text = str(', '.join(map(str, answers)))
    def ClearListAnswers(self):
        answers.clear()
    def printerview(self):
        app = Flask(__name__)

        @app.route('/')
        def home():
            return f"<h1>BFCalc Printer Friendly View</h1>\n{self.ids.list.text}"

        run_simple('localhost',5000,app)

        webbrowser.open_new('localhost:5000')

class RoundCalcScreen(Screen):
    def calc_view(self):
        self.manager.current = "calc_screen"
    def rc_calculate(self):
        RC_DiameterVal = float(self.ids.rc_diameter.text)
        RC_RadiusVal = RC_DiameterVal / 2
        RC_ThicknessVal = float(self.ids.rc_thickness.text)

        RC_FinalCalc = (3.14 * (RC_RadiusVal * RC_RadiusVal) * RC_ThicknessVal) / 144
        RC_FinalCalc = round(RC_FinalCalc,1)
        answers.append(RC_FinalCalc)

        self.ids.rc_board_feet.text = str(RC_FinalCalc)

class RootWidget(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.icon = 'icon.ico'
        return RootWidget()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

Comment: flask is a backend framework. why do you want to use it in that way? what is your purpose? maybe there's other solution

Comment: I wanted to use it to make a printer friendly page of variables in my code.

Comment: maybe better to generate html file and open it?

Comment: How could I do that?

Comment: @LucioRandy you could use the python builtin function `open()`; read docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bad practice to use backend frameworks in that way (they are not used that way at all). It depends on your needs, you can try to use pure HTML instead.

```py
def printerview(self):
    import webbrowser

    file_name = "my_html.html"
    html = f"""<h1>BFCalc Printer Friendly View</h1>\n{self.ids.list.text}"""
    with open(file_name, "w+") as f:
        f.write(html)
    # open html in a browser
    webbrowser.open(file_name)
```

Comment: Ok! Thank you! Although, what happens when the file size gets too big, or will the program overwrite the HTML?

Comment: @LucioRandy you can read more about `open()` function [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), so you can append text or overwrite. And it will be opened anyway if file is big or not.